# In Spring Data, should I be paranoid about handling all possible exceptions?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, nullpointerexception, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have this line of code

```
@Override
public Optional<Category> getCategoryById(int id) {
    return repository.findById(id);
}
```

The documentation of spring data says about the "findById" function:

**Throws:
IllegalArgumentException – if id is null.**

In my case, there is NO WAY it can ever be null, so should I still add try catch block to handle if an error ever occurs?
Also, should try/catch it and handle accordingly? **OR** should I let it be thrown and let

@ControllerAdvice/Exception Handler handle it and return back to the user the error?

Comment: you should use the try\catch if there is checked exception (which IllegalArgumentException is not) or you have some special business-case for this exception. It is OK to let the exception be thrown to the Controller.

Comment: You're right that there's no way it can ever be null. Since `getCategoryById` takes an int primitive, you'll get a `NullPointerException` when calling `getCategoryById`, so it'll never get a chance to call `findById` or throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if you can guarantee that this method will never be passed a non-existing ID you could consider [@SneakyThrows](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows)

from project Lombok.

Assuming this is a larger Project make sure your use of @SneakyThrows is documented.

Comment: so I should always be wary and try to catch ANY POSSIBLE exceptions right?

Comment: In this case where should I catch the IllegalArgumentException? Or better yet, I throw it here and try to catch it where its more meaningful to catch it right?

Comment: Checked exceptions have their uses, but often enough you will notice when they are being redundant/cluttering your code and documentation. I can't tell you any general rule of thumb to follow, except that in your mentioned use cases I'd recommend considering @SneakyThrows

Comment: `@SneakyThrows` is used to throw checked exceptions without declaring them in signature. The question is about shoud the OP handle the **unchecked** exception manually or not.